# regex not tolerant to spaces in minified files

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am upgrading a bash script that basically updates the version and build commit to tag a release. The source (javascript) code can look like this (under) in resp not-minified and minified:

```
// not minified
function(){ 
  version = {
    version: '0.0.6',
    build: '%build%'
  };
  // etc

// minified looks like:
function(){version={version:"0.0.6",build:"%build%"};othercode...
```

In the bash script the line that grabs and changes that content is:

```
sed -i".$BUILD" -e "s/\(version:[   ]*\)'[0-9. ]*-dev'/\1'$TAG$SUFFIX'/" -e "s/\(build:[    ]*\)'%build%'/\1'$BUILD'/" "$COREFILE"
```

but the regex is not tolerant to the minified code. To be honest I am not at home outside javascript and php regex, so I cannot understand yet the logic behind this line and how it is constructed.

If someone could help would be great, I will continue researching to understand this regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here:

1. The minified version uses `"` instead of `'` while your regex is looking only for `'`, to make it work for both replace the occurrences of `'` with `[\"']` in the match part.
2. The *build* part doesn't match even for the non-minified one, you are looking for the string `-dev` after the build number, but it's not there. Use `\(-dev\|\)` to allow the presence of `-dev` or blank.

The command is:

```
sed -i ".$BUILD" -e "s/\(version:[ ]*\)[\"'][0-9. ]*\(-dev\|\)[\"']/\1'$TAG$SUFFIX'/" -e "s/\(build:[ ]*\)[\"']%build%[\"']/\1'$BUILD'/" "$COREFILE"
```